# How to bind this to React ES6 getter and setter functions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

When we want to use `this` from inside an ES6 function, we need to say so in the constructor.

```
export class MyComponent extends React.Component {
     constructor(){
          super();
          this.myFunc = this.myFunc.bind(this);
     }

     myFunc(){
        /*
            Now inside this function, this is now referring to our
            component. We can now access props, states, and refs
            because we declared 'this.myFunc = this.myFunc.bind(this);'
            in the constructor.
        */
     }
}
```

But there are getter functions, and I cannot use the same function binding "syntax" as I do with regular functions:

```
get value(){
   return this.state.oneOfMyValues;
   /*
      The above does not work. this.state is undefined, so is .refs,
      so is .props, because 'this' is not the component itself.
   */
}
```

As I've said, binding value() in the constructor doesn't work:

```
    constructor(){
       super();
       this.myFunc = this.myFunc.bind(this); // This works. It's a regular function.
       this.value = this.value.bind(this); 
       /* No compilation errors for this code, but it doesn't work. The 'this'
          inside the get value() function is still not the component.
       */


       this.state = {}; 
       /* as suggested, but this.state is still undefined from
          inside get value().
       */
    }
```

I cannot use arrow functions on a getter function like I can with a regular function.

HOW do we bind a getter (and probably also a setter) function to the component so that the 'this' inside it refers to the component? As much as possible, I don't want to use `React.createClass({})` "syntax". If I have to go back to the createClass way, what is the point of being able to write getter and setter functions in ES6 if we don't have access to our component via 'this'?

**Usage** This is parentcomponent.js

```
@import React from 'react';
@import { MyComponent } from './mycomponent.js';

export class ParentComponent extends React.Component {

     clickMe = () => {
         console.log(this.refs.myComponent.value);
         /*
             Does not return anything because the get value()
             function of MyComponent has no access to its state,
             props, etc.
         */
     }

     render(){
        return(
             <div className="parent-component">
                  <span onClick={this.clickMe}>Click Me</span>
                  <MyComponent ref="myComponent" />
             </div>
        );
     }
}
```

Comment: Uh... how are you using `value`? I should be impossible for `this` not to refer to the component. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I'm only importing this component into a parent component, but not even putting it on that parent component's JSX. I am doing this so that in a parent component functions, I can simply extract the value out of MyComponent via this.refs.myComponentRef.value instead of event handling from child to parent component.

Comment: `this` should certainly refer to the component instance. It's not (easily) possible to separate a getter from its "host object". Again, please provide a complete example that reproduces the issue.

Comment: As said, this EXACT code will reproduce the issue as long as it's imported to any component, not even put in that parent component's JSX!

Comment: I can only imagine that you are not actually passing an instance of the component, but only the component descriptor. As I said repeatedly, it would be a lot easier if you provide a *complete* example. You are saying that the code you posted already has the issue, but your not accessing `value` anywhere, so that's not true. We are just trying to help you but you are making it difficult :-/

Comment: I'll post where I use MyComponent. I don't think it will help. But I won't post my webpack.config.js or the root component as I don't see how it's relevant.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue: https://jsfiddle.net/hxL51764/. However in your comment you say *"Does not return anything because the get value() function of MyComponent has no access to its state,"*. If the function really didn't have access to the component's state, then accessing `this.state.oneOfMyValues` would likely **throw an error**. The fact that you are getting "nothing" seems to indicate that the value you are trying to access might not have been set yet at that moment.

Comment: To clarify how `this` works, the very fact that you are accessing the property with `myComponent.value`, means that inside the `value` getter, `this` refers to the same value as `myComponent`.

Comment: I disregarded the getter function and used a regular function instead because I cannot get this to work.

Answer (score 3):

Following [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42617757/how-to-bind-this-to-react-es6-getter-and-setter-functions#comment72364378_42617777), it is an issue of `this.state` initialisation . Indeed , in the getter, you are using `this.state. oneOfMyValues` however `this.state` is not defined .

Then , the solution is to declare `this.state = {}` inside the constructor of component.

```
constructor(){
   super();
   this.myFunc = this.myFunc.bind(this); // This works. It's a regular function.
   // this.value = this.value.bind(this); <-- NO NEED
   this.state = {} ; //⚠️
}
```

---

For the binding, you can log the `this.constructor` inside getter and you will be sure that getters and setters does not require manual binding.

```
get value(){
   console.log(this.constructor.name) // Expect to log "MyComponent"
   return this.state.oneOfMyValues;
}
```

Comment: maybe you should remove the `The above does not work` if it's actual working?

Comment: I did this.state = {} in the constructor. I still get "this.state is undefined". I updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your ParentComponent's 'clickMe' handler is not bound to its instance 'this'.

You can either do it here:

`<span onClick={this.clickMe}>Click Me</span>`

to

`<span onClick={this.clickMe`**.bind(this)**`}>Click Me</span>`

OR you can do it in the ParentComponent's constructor:

```
export class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.clickMe = this.clickMe.bind(this);
  }
  ...
}
```

@Felix Kling's JSfiddle illuminated this when he said his code worked. He binds his clickMe, therefore it worked. [jsfiddle.net/hxL51764](http://jsfiddle.net/hxL51764)